# How do i get A dropwdown to populate using Yii2 and Kartiks depDrop widget?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, widget, yii2

I am trying to follow the basic usage scenario from Kartiks site, with three drop downs, the first dropdown the user has just two options "mobile phone" or "tablet", this then posts back to the controller and gets an array of manufacturers e.g Apple or Samsung. these two dropdowns work absolutely fine however the third dropdown gets a list of devices based on the two previous selections. for example if the user selected tablets and apple it would bring a list of ipads etc. the data is returned fine however it is not populated into the dropdown selector. my current train of thinking is that the returned array is not in the correct format however every example i can see returns in a very similar way. the returned data looks like

```
{"output":[{"id":6742,"name":"iPad Air 2"},
   {"id":6741,"name":"iPad mini 3"},
   {"id":5735,"name":"iPad mini 2"},
   {"id":5797,"name":"iPad Air"},
   {"id":5070,"name":"iPad mini Wi-Fi"},
   {"id":5061,"name":"iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular"},
   {"id":3848,"name":"iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G"}, 
   {"id":5071,"name":"iPad 4 Wi-Fi + Cellular"},
   {"id":4621,"name":"iPad 3 Wi-Fi"},{"id":3827,"name":"iPad Wi-Fi + 3G"},
   {"id":4620,"name":"iPad 3 Wi-Fi + Cellular"},
   {"id":3847,"name":"iPad 2 Wi-Fi"},
   {"id":5072,"name":"iPad 4 Wi-Fi"},
   {"id":3828,"name":"iPad Wi-Fi"}],
 "selected":6742}.
```

can anyone see where I'm going wrong. if you need to see my views and controllers let me know and ill upload to pastebin.

Comment: post you model for third dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe i find the problem, i was printing the arrays so i could see the returned data in other ways and i believe this is what was causing the issue. commenting out all of the print_r's fixed the problem.